# Why does a TOP 1 result set using an ORDER BY on an empty column show different results to TOP 5?

Tags: t-sql

When querying a SQL Server table and ORDER BY on a column populated only with ''  I get different results for a TOP 1 compared to a TOP 5. It seems as if the first record is ignored and then the requested number of records are returned - in reverse order.

```
-- Drop temp table if it exists
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [tempdb]..[#OrderByTest];

-- Create temp table
CREATE TABLE [#OrderByTest]
(
    TestValue VARCHAR(1),
    TestName  VARCHAR(20)
 );

-- Populate temp table
INSERT INTO [#OrderByTest] (TestValue, TestName) VALUES
            ('', 'Bravo'),
            ('', 'Foxtrot'),
            ('', 'Charlie'),
            ('', 'Alpha'),
            ('', 'Delta'),
            ('', 'Echo'),
            ('', 'Golf'),
            ('', 'Hotel'),
            ('', 'Indigo'),
            ('', 'Juliet');

--SELECT * FROM #OrderByTest;

-- Query table for TOP 1 and ORDER BY
SELECT TOP 1 TestName FROM #OrderByTest ORDER BY TestValue;

-- Query table for TOP 5 and ORDER BY
SELECT TOP 5 TestName FROM #OrderByTest ORDER BY TestValue;
```

I had rather expected the TOP 1 to return Bravo since it is the first record entered. I had also expected the TOP 5 to return Bravo followed by Foxtrot, Charlie, Alpha and Delta since that is the order in which the records were added.

What I get for the TOP 1 is always Foxtrot and for the TOP 5 I get Echo, Delta, Alpha, Charlie and Foxtrot. It seems that the TOP 5 statement is ignoring the first record and then reversing the next 5 records.

This observation holds true if I alter the TOP 5 to a TOP 3 since then I get Alpha, Charlie, Foxtrot.

Any ideas on what is going on?

Comment: Your ordering does nothing because you order by one column and all fields have the same data in that column. Databases do not guarantee preserving the order. You should order by a second column. `ORDER BY TestValue, TestName;`

Comment: If I remove the ORDER BY statements from my examples then I always get Bravo as first result set - from both of the queries. This makes sense as that was the first record entered.
The ORDER BY seems to be following a different set of rules which do affect the results.

Comment: As there is no way to deterministically order identical values, the optimizer is free to use any order it pleases and return any rows it pleases. You will observe yet another result if you change the table to make `TestName` the primary key, even though we're not mentioning that in the query at all. All of these orders are valid. The fact that it the order is "stable" given the same table structure and data should not be very surprising (the algorithm isn't willfully arbitrary), but it is not something you can count on either.

Comment: If you really wanted to know *precisely* what happened, you can certainly dissect the internal table structures with `DBCC PAGE` and reverse engineer the sorting with either a black-box test or a disassembler, but you could not use those results for anything other than to satisfy your curiosity. Any answer that explained exactly how the optimizer gets its result is dangerous in the sense that people could be tempted to use the results, when they could be invalidated at the very next update of SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a typical example of SQL Server determining his own ordering of records when no explicit ordering is specified. That also counts for all records that seem to be "equal" from an ordering point of view. (In this case: all records.)

So you did specify an ordering, but it has no logical effect, since all records are "equal" according to the ordering you specified. So in the end SQL Server determines the ordering by itself.

Why it is different from a query without an ordering at all? Or different from a query that uses related functionality like TOP, but with other parameter values? Only Microsoft's engineers might know. It's probably related to the complex SQL Server engine's internal implementation.

And strictly speaking it doesn't really matter at all. Otherwise you would have supplied an effective ordering anyway. ;) And for performance reasons: if you do not need an ordering, you should not supply one.

Comment: Thanks. My question was borne out of curiosity rather than performance or a business need. Sounds like I'm not going to find out why it's doing what it's doing, I'll just have to accept it for what it is.

Comment: I already thought so. Yes, things are just what they are. SQL Server just wants to get the results as fast as possible. That determines on it's internal state and implementations. Just be careful with ORDER BY. Sometimes they are necessary to get correct results, but when you only want to sort the results for the client, you could consider to let the client(s) do the sorting. That way, the server can use its processing power for handling more requests.